# Boost python export singleton

Tags: c++, python, boost, singleton

I have a singleton (from boost::serialization):

```
class LogManager : public boost::serialization::singleton<LogManager> { ... };
```

And wrapper for getting instance:

```
inline LogManager &logManager() { return LogManager::get_mutable_instance(); }
```

What's the right way to bind this into boost.python module?

I tried:

```
class_< LogManager, boost::serialization::singleton<LogManager> >("LogManager", no_init)
    ...
;
```

As a result - a lot of ugly error text in console. What's wrong?

Comment: That's it: http://dpaste.com/499848/

Comment: Why do you pass `boost::serialization::singleton<LogManager>` as the second template argument?

Comment: @autopulated that's parent-object from what `LogManager` is inherited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to using `bases<...>` in the second argument as Autopulated pointed out, I think you also want to specifiy `boost::noncopyable` as the third template argument, e.g.

```
bp::class_<LogManager, bp::bases<boost::serialization::singleton<LogManager> >, boost::noncopyable>("LogManager", bp::no_init)
```

**Edit**:
Also, you need have a class declaration for any base classes listed, e.g.

```
bp::class_<boost::serialization::singleton<LogManager>, boost::noncopyable>("Singleton", bp::no_init)
```

Or, if you don't need access to the base class and won't be exporting any other children of `boost::serialization::singleton<LogManager>`, then you can omit specifying the base classes in the first place. That is, the following declaration is just fine if all you want to do is expose the `LogManager` class:

```
bp::class_<LogManager, boost::noncopyable>("LogManager", bp::no_init)
```

Comment: Hm, now it compiles. But what does 3d argument do?

Comment: But when I import the module I get: `RuntimeError: extension class wrapper for base class boost::serialization::singleton<LogManager> has not been created yet`

Comment: As I understand it, it tells boost::python not to make a converter for functions which would return an instance of the wrapped class by value.

Answer (score 1):

You want `bp::bases< boost::serialization::singleton<LogManager> >` as the second template parameter instead.

Comment: ps: `bp::class_< LogManager, bp::bases< boost::serialization::singleton<LogManager> > >("LogManager", bp::no_init)`

Comment: Ah, yes; well see Ray's answer :) Those errors are because it's trying to expose it as copy-constructible, when you want it to be non-copyable.